# Setting a default value in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I would like to set a column default value that is based on another table in my SQLAlchemy model.

Currently I have this:

```
Column('version', Integer, default=1)
```

What I need is (roughly) this:

```
Column('version', Integer, default="SELECT MAX(1, MAX(old_versions)) FROM version_table")
```

How can I implement this in SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.default) gives the following possibilities for `default`:

> A scalar, Python callable, or ClauseElement representing the default
>   value for this column, which will be invoked upon insert if this
>   column is otherwise not specified in the VALUES clause of the insert.

You may look into using a simple function, or you may just be able to use a [`select()` object](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/expression_api.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.select).

In your case, maybe something along the lines of:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import select, func
...
Column('version', Integer, default=select([func.max(1,
    func.max(version_table.c.old_versions))]))
```

Comment: I'm aware of the abilities but for some reason I can't seem to formulate the _right_ query. I'd love some specifics, if you can offer them.

Comment: @ChrisR: Updated the answer with an example.

Comment: That's really close... but in the case where there is no record in version_table max() returns NULL.

Comment: @ChrisR: How about using `func.coalesce`? Something like `func.coalesce(func.max(version_table...), --Default Value Here--)`? I haven't tested this code, however.

Comment: Note this creates a client-side default instead of RDBMS default in the database. See my answer.

Comment: Downvoted because I think a lot of people will actually want the 'server_default' answer, below.

Answer (score 20):

You want [server_default](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.server_default)

```
Column('version', Integer, server_default="SELECT MAX(1, MAX(old_versions)) FROM version_table")
```

Comment: is there a way to modify this to filter on a value being used as part of the insert? for example, `select max(...) from table where table.some_field=some_value`? some_value is one of the values being inserted.

EDIT: sadly it looks like no, postgres doesn't allow this: "The value is any variable-free expression (in particular, cross-references to other columns in the current table are not allowed). Subqueries are not allowed either."

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a DML statement to generate the `default` value, you can simply use the `text` method to indicate that you are passing DML. You may also need an extra set of parentheses if the engine wants to write this inside a `VALUES` clause , e.g.:

```py
from sqlachemy import text
Column('version', Integer, default=text("(SELECT MAX(1, MAX(old_versions)) FROM version_table)"))
```

I've used this technique to use a sequence to override the server default ID generation, e.g.:

```py
Column('version', Integer, default=text("NEXT VALUE FOR someSequence"))
```