# SQLAlchemy ORM before-insert hook

Tags: orm, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to figure out how to write a hook to query the database before inserting a row from the ORM.  I hope to achieve something similar to this:

```
class Table(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    value = Column(Integer, nullable=False)

    def before_insert_hook(self, session):
        """Some arbitrary queries and code.  For example:"""
        if self.value is None:
            self.value = session.query(func.avg(Table.value))\
                    .filter(Table.value > 100).scalar()
```

I've been reading up in the SQLAlchemy docs about ORM events and such, but I can't figure out how to use them to achieve this.

Comment: maybe this can help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9706059/setting-a-default-value-in-sqlalchemy

Comment: If you're using PostgreSQL, theoretically, this can be implemented using CTEs (WITH <query> AS ... INSERT ...). But it looks like that's not yet possible through SQLAlchemy, see open issue https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issue/2551.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looks like you want [ORM Events](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html):

```
from sqlalchemy import event

class Table(Base):
    ...

@event.listens_for(Table, 'before_insert')
def do_stuff(mapper, connect, target):
    # target is an instance of Table
    target.value = ...
```

Comment: what does mapper and connect refer to here ?

Comment: @ArsalanAhmadIshaq
 mapper – the Mapper which is the target of this event.
connection  – the Connection being used to emit INSERT statements for this instance. This provides a handle into the current transaction on the target database specific to this instance.

Comment: @DenysHorobchenko how use this logic when we have target.value = function(parameter) where parameter changes based on request call

Comment: @WajihKatrou I suppose you have some issues with the app architecture, you cannot just get a request object every here and there.

Comment: @DenysHorobchenko this is my issue actually, we are running our api on servelrless architecture. I have no session or context to share with my layers

Comment: @WajihKatrou This question is out of scope of the topic. After all it depends on framework you use, stack, whatever. But the way I see things, ORM events should never be aware of any request parameters. Maybe it worth asking another more precise question on Stackoverflow with all the details.