# Can I make SQLAlchemy defaults apply in the schema too?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, schema, default

As of now, I can define a default (for example, in my model for an Integer column I can say `default=0`) and this default will be respected if I insert from my application through SQLAlchemy. However, in the MySQL schema, the default will be NULL. Is there a way to make the SQLAlchemy defaults be set in the schema too?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47007912/5320906) answer your question?

Comment: It does. I did search for this but I couldn't find it, sorry and thank you.